# Is it possible to find a point value from bounds?

Tags: r, economics

My aim is to find the hourly wages of each observation. But the issue is monthly pay is given in bounds and monthly hours worked are given in levels. What can I do to divide the lower and upper bounds of monthly pay by the hours worked?

### Sample data

```
dput(joint.time)
structure(list(totpinc = structure(c(2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 
5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 
5, 2, 5, 6, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 9, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 5, 
4, 1, 5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 
3, 3, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 
6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 6, 6, 
6, 2, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 6, 2, 2, 
2, 8, 7, 5, 5, 5, 3, 10, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 5, 3, 
10, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 2, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 10, 5, 
10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 1, 11, 11, 1, 3, 6, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 3, 
8, 8, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), labels = c(`ineligible - not currently employed/ self employed` = -2, 
`ineligible - under 16yrs` = -1, `             less than £  215` = 1, 
`£  215 to less than £  435` = 2, `£  435 to less than £  870` = 3, 
`£  870 to less than £1305` = 4, `£1305 to less than £1740` = 5, 
`£1740 to less than £2820` = 6, `£2820 to less than £3420` = 7, 
`£3420 to less than £3830` = 8, `£3830 to less than £4580` = 9, 
`£4580 to less than £6670` = 10, `£6670 or more` = 11, `eligible (current employee or self-emp) - dk/ refuse income` = 12
), label = "total net monthly personal income (for employees & self-employed together)", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), mthhrs = c(150.5, 193.5, 86, 193.5, 
86, 193.5, 86, 193.5, 86, 215, 172, 172, 154.8, 154.8, 154.8, 
150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 43, 43, 43, 
43, 258, 258, 172, 172, 172, 172, 129, 129, 129, 129, 150.5, 
150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 60.2, 60.2, 172, 167.7, 172, 167.7, 
172, 167.7, 51.6, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 167.7, 167.7, 150.5, 
68.8, 68.8, 197.8, 197.8, 86, 68.8, 141.9, 141.9, 141.9, 64.5, 
258, 64.5, 258, 64.5, 258, 64.5, 258, 193.5, 258, 64.5, 172, 
172, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 193.5, 193.5, 391.3, 391.3, 
391.3, 391.3, 391.3, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 86, 86, 86, 202.1, 
163.4, 60.2, 60.2, 60.2, 60.2, 60.2, 103.2, 103.2, 120.4, 159.1, 
159.1, 159.1, 150.5, 86, 150.5, 86, 150.5, 86, 180.6, 193.5, 
180.6, 193.5, 159.1, 34.4, 34.4, 43, 43, 236.5, 236.5, 236.5, 
124.7, 124.7, 90.3, 172, 150.5, 90.3, 172, 150.5, 90.3, 172, 
150.5, 90.3, 172, 150.5, 172, 172, 172, 150.5, 150.5, 167.7, 
167.7, 167.7, 167.7, 159.1, 215, 215, 215, 193.5, 154.8, 193.5, 
154.8, 193.5, 154.8, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 129, 129, 150.5, 172, 
150.5, 172, 150.5, 172, 150.5, 172, 150.5, 172, 150.5, 172, 150.5, 
172, 86, 86, 47.3, 47.3, 47.3, 81.7, 47.3, 47.3, 150.5, 55.9, 
107.5, 55.9, 107.5, 172, 172, 172, 64.5, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 
172, 172, 172, 172, 86, 86, 64.5, 163.4, 150.5, 81.7, 81.7, 81.7, 
172, 103.2, 172, 103.2, 172, 172, 172, 86, 86, 68.8, 150.5, 236.5, 
159.1, 150.5, 159.1, 150.5, 159.1, 150.5, 159.1, 64.5, 64.5, 
64.5, 64.5, 172, 159.1, 103.2, 86, 86, 137.6, 137.6, 64.5, 64.5, 
64.5, 94.6, 94.6, 94.6, 94.6, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 301, 
159.1, 301, 60.2, 60.2, 60.2, 258, 215, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 
120.4, 387, 51.6, 30.1, 159.1, 150.5, 43, 43, 43, 43, 12.9, 154.8, 
154.8, 154.8, 159.1, 77.4, 150.5, 150.5, 77.4, 64.5, 77.4, 64.5, 
77.4, 64.5, 193.5, 193.5, 172, 266.6, 193.5, 172, 266.6, 107.5, 
107.5, 107.5, 107.5, 150.5, 150.5, 129, 129, 81.7, 81.7, 159.1, 
159.1, 159.1, 150.5, 159.1, 150.5, 159.1, 150.5, 258, 258, 258, 
258, 172, 172, 129, 193.5, 167.7, 172, 172, 159.1, 129, 94.6, 
94.6, 94.6, 258, 258, 258, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 154.8, 154.8, 
236.5, 236.5, 236.5, 236.5, 236.5, 68.8, 159.1, 159.1, 215, 133.3, 
133.3, 172, 172, 8.6, 8.6, 8.6, 167.7, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 
129, 129, 60.2, 107.5, 60.2, 107.5, 55.9, 154.8, 154.8, 154.8, 
129, 129, 129, 129, 68.8, 68.8, 107.5, 120.4, 193.5, 184.9, 94.6, 
94.6, 159.1, 159.1, 167.7, 167.7, 167.7, 68.8, 68.8, 68.8, 86, 
86, 361.2, 258, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 206.4, 206.4, 206.4, 206.4, 
206.4, 206.4, 159.1, 129, 129, 129, 154.8, 154.8, 150.5, 77.4, 
150.5, 77.4, 86, 86, 86, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 146.2, 236.5, 
146.2, 236.5, 146.2, 236.5, 86, 86, 150.5, 60.2, 150.5, 60.2, 
150.5, 60.2, 150.5, 60.2, 150.5, 60.2, 150.5, 60.2, 150.5, 60.2, 
150.5, 60.2, 103.2, 202.1, 202.1, 172, 120.4, 154.8, 86, 86, 
283.8, 180.6, 180.6, 180.6, 180.6, 172, 107.5, 172, 107.5, 159.1, 
258, 150.5, 150.5, 116.1, 47.3, 124.7, 129, 129, 301, 301, 159.1, 
159.1, 34.4, 172, 215, 215, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 
159.1, 197.8, 197.8, 172, 159.1, 172, 159.1, 172, 159.1, 172, 
159.1, 193.5, 193.5, 193.5, 193.5)), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")
```

### Goal

1. Divide the lower and upper bounds of monthly pay by the hours worked. This will give me hourly wages in bounds.
2. Using the hourly wage bounds, find the mid-point value.

### Desired output:

```
|    totpinc    | mthhrs | hrwage_bound  | hrwage |
|    --------   | -----  |    --------   |--------|
| £215 - £435   | 150.5  |   1.4 - 2.9   | 2.2    |
| £870 - £1305  | 193.5  |   4.5 - 6.7   | 5.6    |
| £1305 - £1740 | 86     |  15.2 - 20.2  | 17.7   |
| £870 - £1305  | 193.5  |   4.5 - 6.7   | 5.6    |
| £1305 - £1740 | 86     |   15.2 - 20.2 | 17.7   |
| £870 - £1305  | 193.5  |   4.5 - 6.7   | 5.6    |
| £1305 - £1740 | 86     |   15.2 - 20.2 | 17.7   |
| £870 - £1305  | 193.5  |   4.5 - 6.7   | 5.6    |
| £1305 - £1740 | 86     |  15.2 - 20.2  | 17.7   |
| £870 - £1305  | 193.5  |   4.5 - 6.7   | 5.6    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete re-write of my previous answer.

### Approach

```r
yy = 
  attributes(joint.time$totpinc)$labels[
    attributes(joint.time$totpinc)$labels %in% unique(joint.time$totpinc)] |> 
  names() |>
  strsplit("\\D+") |>
  lapply(\(x) x[x != ""]) |>
  lapply(as.numeric)
yy[[1]] = append(yy[[1]], 0, after = 0) # hard-coded 
yy[[11]] = append(yy[[11]], 500000, after = 1) # hard-coded 

lookup = 
  data.frame(seq_len(length(yy)), 
             t(list2DF(yy))) |>
  `colnames<-`(c("label", "minb", "maxb")) 
lookup$maxb = lookup$maxb - 1 # "less than" 

idx = lookup[match(joint.time$totpinc, lookup$label), ]
rm(yy, lookup)

new = 
  within(joint.time, {
    hrwage = lapply(idx[c("minb", "maxb")], 
                    \(x) x / mthhrs) |> list2DF() |> rowMeans() |> round(1)
    totpinc = paste0("£", idx$minb, "-£", idx$maxb) 
    })
```

### Result

```r
> head(new, n = 10)    
       totpinc mthhrs hrwage
1    £215-£434  150.5    2.2
2   £870-£1304  193.5    5.6
3  £1305-£1739   86.0   17.7
4   £870-£1304  193.5    5.6
5  £1305-£1739   86.0   17.7
6   £870-£1304  193.5    5.6
7  £1305-£1739   86.0   17.7
8   £870-£1304  193.5    5.6
9  £1305-£1739   86.0   17.7
10  £870-£1304  215.0    5.1
```

*`hrwage_bound` is not provided and thus missing in the result.*

### Data

```r
joint.time = 
  structure(list(totpinc = structure(c(2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 
                                       5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 
                                       5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 
                                       4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 
                                       5, 2, 5, 6, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                       1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 9, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
                                       2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 5, 
                                       4, 1, 5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 
                                       3, 3, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 
                                       6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 6, 6, 
                                       6, 2, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
                                       5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 
                                       3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 6, 2, 2, 
                                       2, 8, 7, 5, 5, 5, 3, 10, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
                                       6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                       4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 5, 3, 
                                       10, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 
                                       6, 6, 2, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
                                       2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                                       4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
                                       6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 10, 5, 
                                       10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                                       3, 1, 11, 11, 1, 3, 6, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 3, 
                                       8, 8, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
                                       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), labels = c(`ineligible - not currently employed/ self employed` = -2, 
                                                                                             `ineligible - under 16yrs` = -1, `             less than £  215` = 1, 
                                                                                             `£  215 to less than £  435` = 2, `£  435 to less than £  870` = 3, 
                                                                                             `£  870 to less than £1305` = 4, `£1305 to less than £1740` = 5, 
                                                                                             `£1740 to less than £2820` = 6, `£2820 to less than £3420` = 7, 
                                                                                             `£3420 to less than £3830` = 8, `£3830 to less than £4580` = 9, 
                                                                                             `£4580 to less than £6670` = 10, `£6670 or more` = 11, `eligible (current employee or self-emp) - dk/ refuse income` = 12
                                       ), label = "total net monthly personal income (for employees & self-employed together)", class = c("haven_labelled", 
                                                                                                                                          "vctrs_vctr", "double")), mthhrs = c(150.5, 193.5, 86, 193.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               86, 193.5, 86, 193.5, 86, 215, 172, 172, 154.8, 154.8, 154.8, 
                                                                                                                                                                               150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 43, 43, 43, 
                                                                                                                                                                               43, 258, 258, 172, 172, 172, 172, 129, 129, 129, 129, 150.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 60.2, 60.2, 172, 167.7, 172, 167.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                               172, 167.7, 51.6, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 167.7, 167.7, 150.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               68.8, 68.8, 197.8, 197.8, 86, 68.8, 141.9, 141.9, 141.9, 64.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               258, 64.5, 258, 64.5, 258, 64.5, 258, 193.5, 258, 64.5, 172, 
                                                                                                                                                                               172, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 193.5, 193.5, 391.3, 391.3, 
                                                                                                                                                                               391.3, 391.3, 391.3, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 86, 86, 86, 202.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                               163.4, 60.2, 60.2, 60.2, 60.2, 60.2, 103.2, 103.2, 120.4, 159.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                               159.1, 159.1, 150.5, 86, 150.5, 86, 150.5, 86, 180.6, 193.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               180.6, 193.5, 159.1, 34.4, 34.4, 43, 43, 236.5, 236.5, 236.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               124.7, 124.7, 90.3, 172, 150.5, 90.3, 172, 150.5, 90.3, 172, 
                                                                                                                                                                               150.5, 90.3, 172, 150.5, 172, 172, 172, 150.5, 150.5, 167.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                               167.7, 167.7, 167.7, 159.1, 215, 215, 215, 193.5, 154.8, 193.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               154.8, 193.5, 154.8, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 129, 129, 150.5, 172, 
                                                                                                                                                                               150.5, 172, 150.5, 172, 150.5, 172, 150.5, 172, 150.5, 172, 150.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               172, 86, 86, 47.3, 47.3, 47.3, 81.7, 47.3, 47.3, 150.5, 55.9, 
                                                                                                                                                                               107.5, 55.9, 107.5, 172, 172, 172, 64.5, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                               172, 172, 172, 172, 86, 86, 64.5, 163.4, 150.5, 81.7, 81.7, 81.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                               172, 103.2, 172, 103.2, 172, 172, 172, 86, 86, 68.8, 150.5, 236.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               159.1, 150.5, 159.1, 150.5, 159.1, 150.5, 159.1, 64.5, 64.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               64.5, 64.5, 172, 159.1, 103.2, 86, 86, 137.6, 137.6, 64.5, 64.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               64.5, 94.6, 94.6, 94.6, 94.6, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 159.1, 301, 
                                                                                                                                                                               159.1, 301, 60.2, 60.2, 60.2, 258, 215, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               120.4, 387, 51.6, 30.1, 159.1, 150.5, 43, 43, 43, 43, 12.9, 154.8, 
                                                                                                                                                                               154.8, 154.8, 159.1, 77.4, 150.5, 150.5, 77.4, 64.5, 77.4, 64.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               77.4, 64.5, 193.5, 193.5, 172, 266.6, 193.5, 172, 266.6, 107.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               107.5, 107.5, 107.5, 150.5, 150.5, 129, 129, 81.7, 81.7, 159.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                               159.1, 159.1, 150.5, 159.1, 150.5, 159.1, 150.5, 258, 258, 258, 
                                                                                                                                                                               258, 172, 172, 129, 193.5, 167.7, 172, 172, 159.1, 129, 94.6, 
                                                                                                                                                                               94.6, 94.6, 258, 258, 258, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 154.8, 154.8, 
                                                                                                                                                                               236.5, 236.5, 236.5, 236.5, 236.5, 68.8, 159.1, 159.1, 215, 133.3, 
                                                                                                                                                                               133.3, 172, 172, 8.6, 8.6, 8.6, 167.7, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 
                                                                                                                                                                               129, 129, 60.2, 107.5, 60.2, 107.5, 55.9, 154.8, 154.8, 154.8, 
                                                                                                                                                                               129, 129, 129, 129, 68.8, 68.8, 107.5, 120.4, 193.5, 184.9, 94.6, 
                                                                                                                                                                               94.6, 159.1, 159.1, 167.7, 167.7, 167.7, 68.8, 68.8, 68.8, 86, 
                                                                                                                                                                               86, 361.2, 258, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 206.4, 206.4, 206.4, 206.4, 
                                                                                                                                                                               206.4, 206.4, 159.1, 129, 129, 129, 154.8, 154.8, 150.5, 77.4, 
                                                                                                                                                                               150.5, 77.4, 86, 86, 86, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 146.2, 236.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               146.2, 236.5, 146.2, 236.5, 86, 86, 150.5, 60.2, 150.5, 60.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                               150.5, 60.2, 150.5, 60.2, 150.5, 60.2, 150.5, 60.2, 150.5, 60.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                               150.5, 60.2, 103.2, 202.1, 202.1, 172, 120.4, 154.8, 86, 86, 
                                                                                                                                                                               283.8, 180.6, 180.6, 180.6, 180.6, 172, 107.5, 172, 107.5, 159.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                               258, 150.5, 150.5, 116.1, 47.3, 124.7, 129, 129, 301, 301, 159.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                               159.1, 34.4, 172, 215, 215, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 150.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                               159.1, 197.8, 197.8, 172, 159.1, 172, 159.1, 172, 159.1, 172, 
                                                                                                                                                                               159.1, 193.5, 193.5, 193.5, 193.5)), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: hrwage_bound is not provided because it should be calculated (as you did in the very first version). But it appears from your latest version that we could skip that step to find the mid-point value of the hourly wages. :)

Comment: Incorporated your edits.